# Refresh Datagridview after updating database

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I am updating the database in a form and again loading the datagridview but datagridview is not updating . my tried code is below .

this is the code in my sales entry form where if item is sold the quantity should be decreaseed but after saving the sale the stock is not updated in grid.

```
 Private Sub loadallitembtch()
    dgvsearchitem.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Vertical
    On Error Resume Next
    con = New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
    con.Open()

    Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet
    Dim adapter As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter

    sqlstr &= " Select "
    sqlstr &= "   im.iname & ' ' & MfgComTab.comname as [Item], "
    sqlstr &= "   imd.batch As Batch, "
    sqlstr &= "   imd.pscheme As [P Scheme], "
    sqlstr &= "   imd.sscheme As [S Scheme], "
    sqlstr &= "   ROUND(Sum(IIF(txm.ttype = 'S', -txd.iqty, IIF(txm.ttype = 'P', txd.iqty * "
    sqlstr &= "   im.unitratio, IIF(txm.ttype = 'SR', txd.iqty, IIF(txm.ttype = 'PR', "
    sqlstr &= "   -txd.iqty * im.unitratio, IIF(txm.ttype = 'OP', txd.iqty * im.unitratio, "
    sqlstr &= "   0)))))), 2) As [Stock], "
    sqlstr &= "   Unit.unitname As Units, "
    sqlstr &= "   imd.itemid, "
    sqlstr &= "   im.stax as [Tax], "
    sqlstr &= "   imd.prate / im.unitratio As [P Rate], "
    sqlstr &= "   imd.srate / im.unitratio As [Rate] "
    sqlstr &= " From "
    sqlstr &= "   (((([Transaction_Details] As txd Inner Join "
    sqlstr &= "   [Transaction_Mas_Tab] As txm On txd.txid = txm.txid) Inner Join "
    sqlstr &= "   IMasterDetails As imd On txd.itemid = imd.itemid) Inner Join "
    sqlstr &= "   Imaster As im On imd.icode = im.icode) Inner Join "
    sqlstr &= "   Unit On Unit.unitcode = im.sunit) Inner Join "
    sqlstr &= "   MfgComTab On im.mccode = MfgComTab.mccode "
    sqlstr &= " Where "
    sqlstr &= "   txm.billdate Between @date1 And @date2 And "
    sqlstr &= "   txm.isdeleted = 'N' And "
    sqlstr &= "   im.comcode = @comcode "
    sqlstr &= " Group By "
    sqlstr &= "   im.iname, imd.batch, imd.pscheme, imd.sscheme, Unit.unitname, imd.itemid, "
    sqlstr &= "   im.stax, imd.prate / im.unitratio, imd.srate / im.unitratio, im.catcode, "
    sqlstr &= "  im.scatcode, MfgComTab.comname "
    sqlstr &= " Order By  im.iname ASC  "
    adapter.SelectCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sqlstr, con)

    adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date1", globals.fedate)
    adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date2", globals.fsdate)
    adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@comcode", compcode)
    adapter.Fill(ds)
    dgvibatch.Refresh()



    If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then


        dgvibatch.DataSource = ds.Tables(0).DefaultView
        dgvibatch.Columns("itemid").Visible = False
        dgvibatch.Columns("P Scheme").Visible = False
        dgvibatch.Columns("S Scheme").Visible = False
        dgvibatch.Columns("P Rate").Visible = False
        dgvibatch.Columns("units").Visible = False
        dgvibatch.Columns("Item").Width = 150
        dgvibatch.Columns("Rate").Width = 50
        dgvibatch.Columns("Tax").Width = 50
        dgvibatch.Columns("Stock").Width = 50
    Else
        ds.Dispose()

    End If
    con.Close()
```

Comment: Get rid of `On Error Resume Next` and fix any errors rather than trying to ignore them

Comment: tried without on error resume next but not getting any error

Comment: he suggested that so that your code conforms to best practices, it wasn't intended to refresh your datagridview

Comment: Maybe the record isn't inserting/updating into/on the database at all and the refresh is actually working fine?

Comment: the database is updating , when i close the form and re open it the datalagridview loads updated data .